# Sending mail through SES not working

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have written this script

```
#!/bin/bash

TO="abc@gmail.com"
FROM="def@gmail.com"
SUBJECT="test"
MESSAGE="test message"

date="$(date -R)"
echo $date
priv_key="my_access_key"
access_key="my_access_key_id"
signature="$(echo -n "$date" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$priv_key" -binary | base64 -w 0)"
echo $signature
auth_header="X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=$access_key, Algorithm=HmacSHA256, Signature=$signature ,Date=$date"
endpoint="https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"

action="Action=SendRawEmail"
source="Source=$FROM"
to="Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=$TO"
subject="Message.Subject.Data=$SUBJECT"
message="Message.Body.Text.Data=$MESSAGE"

curl -v -X POST -H "Date: $date" -H "$auth_header" --data-urlencode "$message" --data-urlencode "$to" --data-urlencode "$source" --data-urlencode "$action" --data-urlencode "$subject"  "$endpoint"
```

But I am getting this error :

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
  </Error>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I am not able to sort out the problem, that which security token it is talking about. Is this about my credentials. I have create an IAM user with role for sending raw email.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to go to the IAM console and create a role or a user and add a policy to the user to send emails using SES.

You should never write the credentials to your code. There are safer and more correct ways to do so. If you are using EC2, for example, you should add the role to your EC2 instance. Another solution is to use environment variables (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html).

When the user has this policy, you also need to validade the sender email in the SES dashboard in your AWS account. You can either validade the receiver email or create a request to send emails to unregistered receivers.

But first, try adding the IAM permissions and try to make it work.